# JScript Windows Media Player API

Tags: javascript, video, jscript, windows-media-player

in Internet Explorer 8 & 9 I am using this API to control embedded videos in HTML with JavaScript (JScript) (e.g. play, stop, jump to position, ...):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564034%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Now I want to make sure the browser compatibility of this API. It seems that it is a Internet Explorer (JScript) API especially for Windows Media Player 7.0 or higher. Unfortunately I didn't found out the name of the API.

Does anybody know something more about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably mean Windows Media Player ActiveX object. Here's its reference:

[Object Model Reference for Scripting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd563945.aspx)

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. But how can I discribe the dependencies? Is it ActiveX required, Internet Exploer version X or Windows Media Player? I need to find out the compatibility of this reference.

Comment: @julmot: Windows Media Player installed is a must - the ActiveX object is just a wrapper to work with it. Internet Explorer version doesn't matter, but you probably need ActiveX enabled in it. Some API properties and methods may be available only starting with specific WMP version, and may have additional requirements (such as read or read/write access to the media library).

Comment: @julmot: Yes, it's IE-specific thing.